# How do I replace SetProcessAffinityMask()/GetProcessAffinityMask() for systems with more than 32 cores?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, concurrency, affinity

[`SetProcessAffinityMask()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts a `DWORD` mask so it can't be used correctly on systems with more than 32 processors.

Looks like [`SetThreadGroupAffinity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is intended to somehow address the problem, but I can' find any useful code samples that illustrate its usage?

How do I adapt my program using `SetProcessAffinityMask()`/`GetProcessAffinityMask()` for systems with more than 32 processors? Are there any code samples?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `SetProcessAffinityMask()` accepts `DWORD_PTR`.  Since 32 bit versions of the OS do not support >32 cores, this means that you are talking about 64 bit OS. And so the actual limit for `SetProcessAffinityMask()` is therefore 64.

As for how to handle >64 I think the [Supporting Systems That Have More Than 64 Processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463349.aspx) whitepaper will tell you what you need to know.

---

**EDIT**

You state in the comments that your code is 32 bit running on 64 bit OS.

As I understand it, there is limited support for very fine-grained control if you are running inside the 32 bit emulator on a 64 bit OS. The assumption is that if you want to take advantage of these new capabilities you are expected to stop using the emulator.

Comment: The problem is my code is 32-bit and so `DWORD_PTR` is 32-bit too. I've read that whitepaper before asking the question.